# can't get around this pep8 error

Tags: python

```
elif self.model.top_cheese(int(dest)) is not None and \
    self.model.top_cheese(int(dest)).size <\
    self.model.top_cheese(int(origin)).size:
```

it tells me:

```
file.py:102:21: E125 continuation line does not distinguish itself from next logical line
```

It refers to the third line of my code above and i can't figure out how to fix it. If i match the indent of the third line to the first, i get:

```
file.py:102:22: E127 continuation line over-indented for visual indent
```

any ideas?

Comment: How indented is the block following the code you've shown?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Wrap your multi-line expression in parenthesis, remove the backslashes at the end of each line.

Reference: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id11